# How to dynamically populate a Picker using Alloy with Appcelerator?

Tags: dynamic, appcelerator, picker

Is there a way to populate a picker dynamically? This works for option dialogs:

view.xml:

```
<OptionDialog id="distributionPointsOptionDialog">
 <Options>
    <Option id="{dp}"></Option> 
 </Options>
</OptionDialog>
```

controller.js:

```
var dp = [];
for (var j in _data) {
    if (_data[j].country == country) {
        dp.push(_data[j].city + "-" + _data[j].dp_name);
        }
}
$.distributionPointsOptionDialog.options = dp;
```

Is there a way to do the same for a multi-column picker? I tried unsuccessfully to populate a single-column picker.

controller.js:

```
var fs = Ti.Filesystem;
var installedFonts = fs.getFile(fs.resourcesDirectory+ "/fonts").getDirectoryListing();
Ti.API.info("list of resourcesDirectory fonts: " + JSON.stringify(installedFonts));
var fonts = [];
for (var j in installedFonts) {
    fonts.push(installedFonts[j]);
}
$.testPicker.column = fonts;
```

views.xml:

```
<Picker id="testPicker" selectionIndicator="true" height="Ti.UI.SIZE" width="70%" visible="true" zIndex="200" useSpinner="true">
<Column>
   <Row title="{fonts}"></Row>
</Column>
</Picker>
```

This results in an error:

```
ERROR] :      message = "undefined is not an object (evaluating '$model.__transform')";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of wrong things with your implementation.

1. **useSpinner** property has been deprecated, so please remove that from your code.
2. The way you are implementing Options & Pickers is a process of Alloy-Model binding.
3. For dynamic Options, you can simply use below code:

`<OptionDialog id="distributionPointsOptionDialog"></OptionDialog>
$.distributionPointsOptionDialog.options = ['Helvetica', 'Arial', 'Times New Roman'];`

4. `<Option id="{dp}"></Option>` - this syntax is used for Model data binding
5. For Picker, use below code:

`var fonts = [];
fonts[0]=Ti.UI.createPickerRow({title:'Helvetica'});
fonts[1]=Ti.UI.createPickerRow({title:'Arial'});
fonts[2]=Ti.UI.createPickerRow({title:'Times New Roman'});
fonts[3]=Ti.UI.createPickerRow({title:'Georgia'});
$.testPicker.add(fonts);`

OR

`var column = Ti.UI.createPickerColumn();
    column.add( Ti.UI.createPickerRow({ title: 'Helvetica' }) );
    column.add( Ti.UI.createPickerRow({ title: 'Arial' }) );
    column.add( Ti.UI.createPickerRow({ title: 'Times New Roman' }) );
    column.add( Ti.UI.createPickerRow({ title: 'Georgia' }) );
$.testPicker.columns = [column];`

For Pickers, in short, you can either use **$.testPicker.add()** method, or you can set columns like this **$.testPicker.columns = [column1, column2, column1, ...]**

Read more here [How to add Columns or Rows in Pickers](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.Picker-method-add)

or

[How to add column(s) in Picker](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.Picker-property-columns)

Comment: Hey Prashant! Many thanks for the clear explanation. It worked perfectly (there was just a Row missing in the column.add method)

Comment: Yeah, I skipped that for you to explore and you did that :) and I hope you have better understanding now on how to effectively use Titanium Docs & API